# pie css not working on anchor tags

Tags: css, css3pie

I am using pie css for adding border radius to the elements. but its not working on anchor tags which i am having in my main navigation. except anchor tags its working on all elements.
here is the css-

```
nav.first li a{
position:relative;
color:#681001;
display:block;
margin-left:5px;
-moz-border-radius:8px 8px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px 8px 0px 0px;
border-radius:8px 8px 0px 0px;
border:1px solid #cb0000;
background:#fedf80;
behavior:url(PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc)
}
```

I have used jquery.corner.js also that is providing border radius but removes the borders.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You have to add postion:relative for IE specific stylesheet not in your main stylesheet...

1. make the target element position:relative, or
2. make the ancestor element position:relative and give it a z-index.

if you have any doubts please go through the below URL...
http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/